# How to access Statemint/Statemine assets in a parachain?

Tags: kusama, xcm, assets, statemint

Statemint/Statemine provides a first-class interface for creating, managing, and using both fungible and non-fungible assets.
Token such as `USDT` are minted on it.

What methods are possible to interact with Statemint/Statemine's assets into a parachain?

Answer (score 2):

(Not financial advice) If your question is about how to bring liquidity from stablecoins like USDT into Polkadot and Kusama ecosystem? Currently it is available with Bitfinex withdrawals to Statemint and Statemine parachains for Polkadot and Kusama ecosystem respectively.

**1) You withdraw your USDT from an exchange like Bitfinex into Statemint/Statemine**

See Statemine example:
https://support.polkadot.network/support/solutions/articles/65000181634-how-to-withdraw-usdt-from-bitfinex-on-statemine

See that Statemint (Polkadot) is also now recently available:
https://www.bitfinex.com/posts/840

**2) You then transfer it across the Polkadot/Kusama ecosystem respectively:**

See Statemine example:
https://support.polkadot.network/support/solutions/articles/65000181118-how-to-transfer-tether-usdt-on-statemine

FYI on what is Statemint and Statemine:
https://support.polkadot.network/support/solutions/articles/65000181800-what-is-statemint-and-statemine-and-how-do-i-use-them-